# NoMethodError: undefined method `require' in rubyfiddle.com

Tags: ruby

http://rubyfiddle.com/ has some limitations on its usage, and it doesn't even let me require a gem. This code in my fiddle:

```
require 'net/http'
```

throws the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `require' for Object:Class
```

Comment: Try Cloud9 IDE.

Comment: this is for a work example and I have to use rubyfiddle.com

Comment: On the [github page](https://github.com/jwo/ruby-fiddle-web#todo) it says: _TODO Allow inclusion of gems like ActiveSupport, RSpec_.

Comment: It doesn't even appear to run its own example. Looks the page is a work in progress. Maybe report an issue on their github page?

Comment: Think about it from the viewpoint of the hoster: it's running Ruby on their system. Allowing arbitrary functionality to run on their machine could open them up to all *sorts* of vulnerabilities and liabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` and `load` are methods in the [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html) module namespace, and it looks like they are both unavailable in the RubyFiddle sandbox, e.g.

```
puts Kernel.methods
```

If you want to play around with Net::HTTP, give a REPL a try like [irb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) or [pry](http://pryrepl.org/). Note: other online interactive ruby shells (e.g. [TryRuby.org](http://tryruby.org/)) also have a similar limitation.